# Java: find combination days in a list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, combinations, distance

I am trying to calculate the duration in days of the trips as in the following list (each DepArr object represents a trip with departure and arrival day).
Basically, I would like to count the days of a trip (arr-dep) and if the trip N arrive on the same day of the trip N+1, then the arrival day has to be splitted between the two trips. This is also valid if the departure is shared with previous trip and for trip N+2 and so on (see examples below).

I created the following code to calculate the days of a trip (also if departure/arrival are the same), but I am not able to make it work for example when the arrival day is the same of next departure, like example D, E and F below.

Any idea or more elegant way to manage it? 
Thank you.

```
    List<DepArr> personTrips = new ArrayList<DepArr>();
    personTrips.add(new DepArr(2, 2));      // A. espected result = 1.00 --> 0.50 + 0.50        
    personTrips.add(new DepArr(3, 3));      // B. espected result = 0.66 --> 0.33 + 0.33
    personTrips.add(new DepArr(3, 6));      // C. espected result = 3.33 --> 0.33 + 1.00 + 1.00 + 1.00
    personTrips.add(new DepArr(7, 8));      // D. espected result = 1.50 --> 1.00 + 0.50
    personTrips.add(new DepArr(8, 9));      // E. espected result = 1.00 --> 0.50 + 0.50
    personTrips.add(new DepArr(9, 10));     // F. espected result = 0.75 --> 0.50 + 0.25
    personTrips.add(new DepArr(10, 10));    // G. espected result = 0.50 --> 0.25 + 0.25
    personTrips.add(new DepArr(10, 11));    // H. espected result = 1.25 --> 0.25 + 1.00
    personTrips.add(new DepArr(12, 12));    // I. espected result = 1.00 --> 0.50 + 0.50
    personTrips.add(new DepArr(13, 13));    // J. espected result = 0.66 --> 0.33 + 0.33
    personTrips.add(new DepArr(13, 14));    // K. espected result = 1.33 --> 0.33 + 1.00        
    personTrips.add(new DepArr(15, 16));    // L. espected result = 2.00 --> 1.00 + 1.00    

    for (int i = 0; i < personTrips.size(); i++) {

    DepArr personPrev = personTrips.get(i-1);   
    DepArr personThis = personTrips.get(i);                     
    DepArr personNext = personTrips.get(i+1);   

    double base =  personThis.getArr() - personThis.getDep();
    double depQuote = 0.5;
    double arrQoute = 0.5;      

    // dep this = arr this
    if(personThis.getDep() == personThis.getArr()) {        
        base = base + depQuote + arrQoute;  
    }       
    // *** DEP      
    // dep this = arr this = dep next
    if(personThis.getDep() == personThis.getArr() && personThis.getArr() == personNext.getDep()) {      
        base = base - 1 + 2 * (depQuote + arrQoute) / 3;
    }       
    // dep this = dep prev = arr prev
    if(personThis.getDep() == personPrev.getDep() && personPrev.getDep() == personPrev.getArr()) {      
        base = base + 1 * (depQuote + arrQoute) / 3;    
    }       
    // dep this = arr prev
    if(personThis.getDep() == personPrev.getArr() && personThis.getDep() != personThis.getArr() && personPrev.getDep() != personPrev.getArr()) {        
        base = base + 1 * (depQuote + arrQoute) / 2;
    }       
    // *** ARR      
    // arr this = dep next = arr next
    if(personThis.getArr() == personNext.getDep() && personNext.getDep() == personNext.getArr()) {      
        base = base + 1 * (depQuote + arrQoute) / 3;    
    }       
    // dep this = arr this = arr prev
    if(personThis.getDep() == personThis.getArr() && personThis.getDep() == personPrev.getArr()) {      
        base = base - 1 + 2 * (depQuote + arrQoute) / 3;
    }       
    // arr this = dep next
    if(personThis.getArr() == personNext.getDep() && personThis.getDep() != personThis.getArr() && personNext.getDep() != personNext.getArr()) {        
        base = base + 1 * (depQuote + arrQoute) / 2;    
    }       
    // *** DEP and ARR
    // dep this = arr this = dep prev = arr prev
    if(personThis.getDep() == personThis.getArr() && personThis.getDep() == personPrev.getArr() && personPrev.getDep() == personPrev.getArr()) {        
        base = base - 1 + 2 * (depQuote + arrQoute) / 4;
    }       
    // dep this = arr this = dep next = arr next
    if(personThis.getDep() == personThis.getArr() && personThis.getArr() == personNext.getDep() && personNext.getDep() == personNext.getArr()) {        
        base = base - 1 + 2 * (depQuote + arrQoute) / 4;
    }

    Double usage = base;
    log.info(i + " " + personThis.getDep() + " " + personThis.getArr() + " " + usage);
}
```

Comment: In my humble opinion i suggest you ask one question at a time and specify what problem you have encountered instead of `Cannot make it work` . Also specify at what part you want help. Calculating the days?Checking if the depart times are the same?

Comment: Need more clarity on what is the input and what is the expected output. Better to share the expected and actual output. It'll help people to investigate faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a `Map` for counting the *frequency* of each mentioned day.

That way the order of the `DepArr` objects don't matter, and it greatly simplifies the code.

E.g. like this, using Java 8 Streams:

```java
Map<Integer, Long> dayFreq = personTrips.stream()
        .flatMap(t -> Stream.of(t.getDep(), t.getArr()))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
for (DepArr trip : personTrips) {
    double days = 1.0 / dayFreq.get(trip.getDep())
                + 1.0 / dayFreq.get(trip.getArr());
    if (trip.getArr() > trip.getDep())
        days += trip.getArr() - trip.getDep() - 1;
    System.out.printf("%2s %2d %.2f%n", trip.getDep(), trip.getArr(), days);
}
```

*Output*

```
 2  2 1.00
 3  3 0.67
 3  6 3.33
 7  8 1.50
 8  9 1.00
 9 10 0.75
10 10 0.50
10 11 1.25
12 12 1.00
13 13 0.67
13 14 1.33
15 16 2.00
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 thing.

1. Making a Class `Trip` which is has 3 fields. `Date of departure`,`Date of arrival`,`Duration`.
2. Getters for the said fields.(setters are not needed. this values gonna be provided on the constructor,except of the duration which is up to you to calulate).
3. User LocalDateTime with it's very usefull methods,`isAfter`,`isBefore`,`getDay` etc..

You can decide if two days is equal if the `getDayOfYear`,`getYear` return the same result(do not know if there is a build in method that gonna do that for you).

That way you can easily compare two dates and also calculate the duration.

LocalDateTime is you biggest ally here. You can check all of the classes methods on [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) of course.